# How to do something before executing each Concat element in RxJava?

Tags: android, kotlin, system.reactive

I'm writing api synchronization module in kotlin. I want to show people what app is currently downloading but I have problem with that. Let me show you example code of what I'm doing:

```
private val downloadProcessNameList = listOf(
    "Controller 1",
    "Controller 2"
)

private val downloadList = listOf(
    controller1.allFromApi(),
    controller2.allFromApi()
)

init {
    liveDownloadPercent.postValue(0)
    liveSavePercent.postValue(0)

    mDisposable.add(
        Maybe.concat(downloadList)
            .doOnNext { liveDownloadStatus.postValue(downloadProcessNameList[i]) }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(
                {
                    Log.i(LOG_HEADER, it.size.toString())

                    i++
                },
                {
                    Log.e(LOG_HEADER, it.message)
                },
                {
                    Log.i(LOG_HEADER, "onComplete")
                }
            )
    )
}
```

The problem is with this line

```
.doOnNext { liveDownloadStatus.postValue(downloadProcessNameList[i]) }
```

It is executed right after first cotroller response and the user don't see what app is doing in first place. I've searched everywhere and I can't find right answer. How to show information from **downloadProcessNameList[i]** before beginning Concat? Sure I can show that outside Maybe.concat but I don't like it? Maybe you have idea what can be done.

Thank you in advance,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use doOnSubcribe() it is called as soon as observable subscribed